# When a tech document states that something is IP-Aware was does that specifically mean?

Tags: terminology

I need a class room definition for IP-aware for a research assignment. I.E. something that would be used, lets say, in a dictionary. Does anyone know or provide me with a link to a defintiion, I am having no luck with searches. Are IP-Aware devices only devices that can read/find/make decisions based on IP addresses. For example a router would be one, but a network printer would not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never come across the phrase "IP aware" specifically (though I've worked in networking for over ten years); I'm not sure that it has a generally-accepted meaning.

It's possible that some people/companies have given it a meaning for their products - can you provide the context in which you found the phrase?

(And are you sure it's to do with networking? For instance, "IP" often stands for "Intellectual Property".)

Comment: A tech document I was researching stated: "Complete inventory of IP-Aware applications a peripherals with dependencies on network back bone." For my understanding, I am just trying to determine exactly what that means in context. The subject matter of the paper is on a IPv6 conversion.

Comment: Part of this leads me to believe that they are basically referring to anything with an IP address, knowledge of IP addresses, or the ability to interact with IPs. In other words, pretty much anything on a network. However, some of what I am seeing out there in google searching makes believe that it could only be IP 'smart' devices, i.e. routers, switches, network management software ...but not things like printers.

Comment: I think this just confirms my suspicions - there isn't a generally-accepted meaning for the term, so different people use it to mean different things...